# Result Delegate never called to Load table in DynamoDB in Unity3D (C#)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, load, amazon-dynamodb

- Unity Version : 2017.3.1f1
- AWS Service : DynamoDB
- Testing Environment : Mac OSX on the editor

**Scenario**

Trying to load a table from Dynamo DB but having weird issues.

It loads extremely well when I use the primary HASH key that is valid but when I supply a wrong HASH key (key that is not present in the database), the delegate is never called.

**Source**

```
private void performLoadOperation()
{
    ExperienceListing _experienceListing = null;
    string _ISEN = "21-89297083-ebe3-40b2-a269-3cfe80922fed";

    DH.log ("About to load ");
    Context.LoadAsync<ExperienceListing>
    (_ISEN, (_result)=>
        { 
            Debug.Log ("result returned - " + _result.Result.Title);
            if(_result.Exception == null)
            {
                _experienceListing = _result.Result as ExperienceListing;
                Debug.Log ("Title - " + _result.Result.Title);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log ("Exception - " + _result.Exception);
            }
        }
    );
}


[DynamoDBTable("ExperienceListing")]
public class ExperienceListing
{
    [DynamoDBHashKey]   // Hash key.
    public string ISEN{ get; set; }
    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public string Blurb{get;set;}
    [DynamoDBProperty]
    public int Views{ get; set; }
    [DynamoDBProperty]  
    public int Rating{ get; set; }
}
```

**Test Case**

For the above performLoadOperation(), the delegate is being called properly. Now let's say that I change _ISEN variable to a string that is not present in the database, the delegate never gets called. I would like to note that, the internet is available.

**Request**

1. Am I supposed to give the correct hash key at all times and should understand that the delegate would never be called for invalid/wrong hash key's?

---

**EDIT**

The following worked for me but still it is wierd.

```
private void performLoadOperation()
{
    ExperienceListing _experienceListing = null;
    string _ISEN = "08c0ba69-af71-4017-afb8-5040f7033b33";

    DH.log ("About to load ");
    Context.LoadAsync<ExperienceListing>
    (_ISEN, (_result)=>
        { 

            if(_result.Exception == null)
            {
                _experienceListing = _result.Result as ExperienceListing;
                Debug.Log ("No Exception");
                if(_experienceListing == null)
                {
                    Debug.Log ("Experience Listing is null");
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log ("Experience Listing not null - " + _experienceListing.Title);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log ("Exception - " + _result.Exception.Message);
            }
            if(_result == null)
            {
                Debug.Log ("Return result is null");
            }
        }, null
    );
}
```

When none of the "_result" is access for print logs, the logs were printed. As from advice from @MikeDinescu , tested with breakpoints which gave indication that delegate was called.

With the above solution, when the _result is still not null - it is required to manually check _experienceListing to know whether DyanomoDB has any of the tables from the hash key.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, not as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delegate should be called regardless of whether the operation retrieves a result or not. In the case when there is no item matching the key, `Result` would be null and Exception would contain the error details.

However, the callback lambda contains a null reference exception right on the first line. Most likely what is happening is the lambda is invoked but throws an exception right away because it’s trying to dereference the Null result.

Are you sure it isn’t called? Have you tried putting a break point on the first line of the lambda?

The other thing to try would be to change the first `Debug.WriteLine` in the callback lambda to be a simple string, removing the part that attempts to dereference `_result.Result`, and then check if the debug message is printed even when the result is an exception.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. I have added the code to the edit section of my question. It is still weird though.

Comment: @karsnen glad it worked. What is still weird? Perhaps I can help clarify further

Comment: Whenever I try to access `_result` within that delegate for an invalid hash key, it never runs.  For example, `Debug.Log (_result.Title);` should throw an error, if the table wasn't to be found.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure exactly why it’s not throwing if it really isn’t throwing but it is entirely possible that the exception is actually thrown but because it’s on a background thread you are not seeing it explicitly. You could wrap the whole body of the callback in a try-catch and log any exception. Then see if that tells you more.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will dig deep with Exception handling when I get back.